# How receive meaningful error from StepVerifier when mock object didn't setup in JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito, project-reactor

I have simple example for demonstration of problem. Here is simple example of service depending on repository, very common for Spring Framework.

**Foo.java**

```java
package dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private UUID   id;
    private String name;

}
```

**FooRepository.java**

```java
package dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.repositories;

import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.model.Foo;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface FooRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Foo, UUID> {

}
```

**DefaultFooService.java**

```java
package dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.services;

import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.model.Foo;
import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.repositories.FooRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Service
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    private final FooRepository fooRepository;

    public DefaultFooService(FooRepository fooRepository) {
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Foo> findAll() {
        return fooRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

**DefaultFooService.java**

```java
package dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.services;

import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.model.Foo;
import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.repositories.FooRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Service
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    private final FooRepository fooRepository;

    public DefaultFooService(FooRepository fooRepository) {
        this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Foo> findAll() {
        return fooRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

**DefaultFooServiceTest.java**

```java
package dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.services;

import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.model.Foo;
import dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.repositories.FooRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.UUID;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DefaultFooServiceTest {

    @Mock
    FooRepository fooRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    DefaultFooService fooService;

    @Test
    void testFindAll() {

        var id1 = UUID.fromString("e00ab7f4-14eb-40d4-9cdb-109e8f88c773");
        var id2 = UUID.fromString("809359bd-2d5b-4eb7-b666-f520c628027b");

        var foo1 = new Foo();
        foo1.setId(id1);

        var foo2 = new Foo();
        foo2.setId(id2);

        var publisher = fooService.findAll();

        var fooExpected1 = new Foo();
        fooExpected1.setId(id1);

        var fooExpected2 = new Foo();
        fooExpected2.setId(id2);

        StepVerifier.create(publisher)
                    .expectNext(fooExpected1, fooExpected2)
                    .verifyComplete();

    }

}
```

You can see that mock for `dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.services.DefaultFooService#findAll` haven't been setup in `dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.services.DefaultFooServiceTest#testFindAll`.

When I run test I will receive such error:

```sh
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test FAILED
Mar 10, 2022 8:36:14 AM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator lambda$logTestDescriptorExclusionReasons$7
INFO: 0 containers and 1 tests were Method or class mismatch

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.toVerifierAndSubscribe(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:867)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:823)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:815)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:682)
    at dev.stanislavmachel.reactiveexperements.services.DefaultFooServiceTest.testFindAll(DefaultFooServiceTest.java:75)


DefaultFooServiceTest > testFindAll() FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at DefaultFooServiceTest.java:75
```

As you can see output from test only point to `DefaultFooServiceTest.java:75` -> to `reactor.test.StepVerifier.LastStep#verifyComplete` call in test itself and not provide any useful information. If go with debugger to some methods provided in call stack it also not give any useful information.

This test is simple and it is really easy to find not properly setup mock, but if class have more than 3 dependencies it can be challenging sometimes.

Does it possible to somehow turn on more meaningful errors with Reactor Project? May be here is more suitable testing approach or framework which can give more descriptive information to developer? For example point to method which mock wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it possible to somehow turn on more meaningful errors with Reactor Project? May be here is more suitable testing approach or framework which can give more descriptive information to developer? For example point to method which mock wasn't found.

To some extent...
The rationale is that when you do `StepVerifier.create(...)`, the publisher parameter is not checked for null by any of the overloads, therefore nulls get lazily propagated to `DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:867`.
Sounds like a design issue that probably won't be ever fixed at least for a minor version upgrade because such a fix may break existing projects.

##### Option 1

So, having that in mind, you can create guarded versions of the create method overloads and somehow mark the `StepVerifier.create` methods deprecated for your project:

```java
@UtilityClass
public final class GuardedStepVerifier {

    public static <T> StepVerifier.FirstStep<T> create(final Publisher<? extends T> publisher) {
        if ( publisher == null ) {
            throw new AssertionError("publisher not set up");
        }
        return StepVerifier.create(publisher);
    }

    public static <T> StepVerifier.FirstStep<T> create(final Publisher<? extends T> publisher, final long n) {
        if ( publisher == null ) {
            throw new AssertionError("publisher not set up");
        }
        return StepVerifier.create(publisher, n);
    }

    public static <T> StepVerifier.FirstStep<T> create(final Publisher<? extends T> publisher, final StepVerifierOptions options) {
        if ( publisher == null ) {
            throw new AssertionError("publisher not set up");
        }
        return StepVerifier.create(publisher, options);
    }

}
```

Compare the following tests:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public final class DefaultFooServiceTest {

    private static final Foo foo1 = new Foo(UUID.fromString("e00ab7f4-14eb-40d4-9cdb-109e8f88c773"));
    private static final Foo foo2 = new Foo(UUID.fromString("809359bd-2d5b-4eb7-b666-f520c628027b"));

    @Mock
    private FooRepository fooRepositoryMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private DefaultFooService unit;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        if ( false ) {
            Mockito.doReturn(Flux.just(foo1, foo2))
                    .when(fooRepositoryMock)
                    .findAll();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testFindAllWithStepVerifier() {
        StepVerifier.create(unit.findAll())
                .expectNext(foo1, foo2)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void testFindAllWithGuardedStepVerifier() {
        GuardedStepVerifier.create(unit.findAll())
                .expectNext(foo1, foo2)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

}
```

`testFindAllWithStepVerifier` output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.reactivestreams.Publisher.subscribe(org.reactivestreams.Subscriber)" because "publisher" is null
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.toVerifierAndSubscribe(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:867)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:823)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:815)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:682)
    at q71419972.DefaultFooServiceTest.testFindAllWithStepVerifier(DefaultFooServiceTest.java:40)
    ...
```

`testFindAllWithGuardedStepVerifier` output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: publisher not set up
    at q71419972.GuardedStepVerifier.create(GuardedStepVerifier.java:15)
    at q71419972.DefaultFooServiceTest.testFindAllWithGuardedStepVerifier(DefaultFooServiceTest.java:45)
    ...
```

The former is really obscure even for a simple test, but the latter *can* point something set up wrong at least by spotting the mistake (sure, not literally right in the logs, but only peeking into the source code using the stacktrace).
Attempting to make it a bit more informative and meaningful probably won't work too because there is no a way to take that info from.

However...
Here goes the following:

##### Option 2

Make your mocks annotated with `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)`.
This will produce the following outputs for the default and "guarded" versions respectively (I marked the diffs with ):

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectNext(Foo(id=e00ab7f4-14eb-40d4-9cdb-109e8f88c773))" failed (expected: onNext(Foo(id=e00ab7f4-14eb-40d4-9cdb-109e8f88c773)); actual: onError(org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: 
You have a NullPointerException here:
-> at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
because this method call was *not* stubbed correctly:
-> at q71419972.DefaultFooService.findAll(DefaultFooService.java:22)
fooRepositoryMock.findAll();
))

    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failPrefix(MessageFormatter.java:104)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.fail(MessageFormatter.java:73)
    at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.failOptional(MessageFormatter.java:88)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.lambda$addExpectedValue$10(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:501)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$SignalEvent.test(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:2218)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onSignal(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1490)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onExpectation(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1438)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultVerifySubscriber.onError(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:1091)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.reportThrowInSubscribe(Operators.java:232)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8472)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.toVerifierAndSubscribe(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:867)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:823)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder$DefaultStepVerifier.verify(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:815)
    at reactor.test.DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.verifyComplete(DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.java:682)
  at q71419972.DefaultFooServiceTest.testFindAllWithStepVerifier(DefaultFooServiceTest.java:41)
 OR
  at q71419972.DefaultFooServiceTest.testFindAllWithGuardedStepVerifier(DefaultFooServiceTest.java:48)
    ...
    Suppressed: org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: 
You have a NullPointerException here:
-> at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8469)
because this method call was *not* stubbed correctly:
-> at q71419972.DefaultFooService.findAll(DefaultFooService.java:22)
fooRepositoryMock.findAll();
```

As you can see, the error above reports that the `FooRepository.findAll` method was not stubbed, but the overall stack trace is longer.

You choose.